# How to add external libraries to android virtual device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have an android application which uses an external library. I want to run that application on Android Virtual Device. The android documentation says:

> If your application declares a uses-library element in its manifest
>   file, the application can only run on a system image in which that
>   external library is present. If you want to run your application on an
>   emulator, create an AVD that includes the required library. Usually,
>   you must create such an AVD using an Add-on component for the AVD's
>   platform (for example, the Google APIs Add-on contains the Google Maps
>   library).

How to create the AVD including the library file.

Comment: "I have an android application which uses an external library" -- libraries that developers normally use are simply compiled into the app. The only reason why you would use `<uses-library>` is because some documentation from a device manufacturer or custom ROM developer told you to use `<uses-library>`. That device manufacturer or custom ROM developer would be responsible for giving you an emulator image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`<uses-library>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html) is used to restrict app availability in Google Play based on the availability of a library on user's device, like Google Maps. It's not used to declare the third party libraries that you've compiled in your project. That is done in the `build.gradle` file.

More info over here: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#declareDeps